# How to use xsl:stream, xsl:accumulator, xs:fork from XSLT 3.0?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-3.0

I am reading the W3C documentation for XSLT 3.0 [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-xslt-30-20131212/). I wonder how to use these elements:

```
(1) xsl:decimal-format
(2) xsl:stream
(3) xsl:accumulator
(4) xsl:accumulator-rule
(5) xsl:fork
```

Apparently these are some of the less used elements. As the examples given there are limited, answers provided here will benefit future learners of XSLT. Could someone please demonstrate how to use them?

I know that is a lot to answer. So I will upvote any correct partial answer, in the hope that it will be useful to others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xsl:decimal-format` has been in the spec since version 1.0; the other elements you cite are new in version 3.0, and are all associated with streaming (that is, the ability to process a source document "on the fly", without loading the whole tree in memory).

```
<xsl:stream href="in.xml">
   ...do something...
</xsl:stream>
```

has essentially the same effect as

```
<xsl:for-each select="doc('in.xml')">
   ...do something...
</xsl:for-each>
```

except that the "do something" is streamed (which means it must conform to the rules for streamability). For example, if you want to find out the average salary of a large number of employees, you could do

```
<xsl:stream href="in.xml">
   <result><xsl:value-of select="avg(//employee/@salary)"/></result>
</xsl:stream>
```

What if you want to compute the min and max salary during a single streaming pass of the input document? xsl:fork and accumulators both provide solutions to this problem. xsl:fork allows you to specify two or more computations that happen during the same pass, effectively in parallel:

```
<xsl:stream href="in.xml">
   <result>
     <xsl:fork>
        <xsl:sequence>
           <min><xsl:value-of select="min(//employee/@salary)"/></min>
        </xsl:sequence>
        <xsl:sequence>
           <max><xsl:value-of select="max(//employee/@salary)"/></max>
        </xsl:sequence>
     </xsl:fork>
   </result>
</xsl:stream>
```

xsl:accumulator allows you to define processing that occurs effectively as a side-effect of reading the document:

```
<xsl:accumulator name="min-salary" initial-value="10000000">
  <xsl:accumulator-rule match="employee" 
      select="if (@salary lt $value) then @salary else $value"/>
</xsl:accumulator>
```

and you can then at any point in processing read off the minimum salary so far by calling `accumulator-before('min-salary')`.

Comment: So when is an accumulator evaluated? How is it related to streaming?

Comment: When streaming, accumulators are evaluated progressively as a document is being read: every start-element or end-element event causes any matching accumulator rules to fire, which potentially update the value of the accumulator for that node. Accumulators also work for non-streaming documents, but they are designed to enable computations to be performed when streaming that would otherwise require multiple passes over an input document (for example, creating a back-of-book index).

Answer (score 2):

**`<xsl:decimal-format>`**
Found a good example here: [MSDN xsl:decimal-format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/ms256229%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Example reduced: Declaring `<xsl:decimal-format>` in the XSL

```
<xsl:decimal-format name="example" decimal-separator="." grouping-separator=","  
 infinity="INFINITY" minus-sign="-" NaN="Not a Number" percent="%"
 per-mille="m" zero-digit="0" digit="#" pattern-separator=";" />
```

Using it with `<xsl:format-number>`

```
<xsl:value-of select="format-number(1 div 0, '###,###.00', 'example')"/>
```

Output:  `INFINITY`
Reference: http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-xslt-30-20131212/#dt-decimal-format
Full working demo tested on http://exselt.net/demo:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="decimalformat.xsl"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="html"/>   
<xsl:decimal-format name="example" decimal-separator="." grouping-separator=","
  infinity="INFINITY" minus-sign="-" NaN="Not a Number" percent="%"
  per-mille="m" zero-digit="0" digit="#" pattern-separator=";" /> 
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <xsl:value-of select="format-number(1 div 0, '###,###.00', 'example')"/>  
    </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Strange. I had to change the version of the stylesheet from 3.0 to 1.0 to make it work.

Comment: Also wondered about it and just updated answer with working example